# Getting all results on the same array

Tags: json, group-by, jq

I have been struggling with these for hours and I am pretty sure there is something I am missing.

Given this JSON:

```
[
{
  "LAST_JOB_POD":"gitlab-web-65-gwwwh",
  "STARTED_AT":"31-05-2018-18:18:48",
  "FINISHED":"false",
  "FIRST_INDEXED":"0",
  "LAST_INDEXED":"3143",
  "failed_projects":{
    "1082": "4:Deadline Exceeded, trace",
    "1273": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'",
    "2492": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "3060": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)"
  }
},
{
  "LAST_JOB_POD":"gitlab-web-65-gwwwh",
  "STARTED_AT":"31-05-2018-18:18:48",
  "FINISHED":"false",
  "FIRST_INDEXED":"0",
  "LAST_INDEXED":"3143",
  "failed_projects":{
    "5570": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6103": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6188": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6695": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6721": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6728": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6747": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)"
  }
},
{ 
  "LAST_JOB_POD":"gitlab-web-65-gwwwh",
  "STARTED_AT":"31-05-2018-18:18:48",
  "FINISHED":"false",
  "FIRST_INDEXED":"0",
  "LAST_INDEXED":"3143",
  "failed_projects":{
    "6760": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6939": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6941": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6942": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "6947": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)",
    "7201": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'",
    "7707": ", trace - [\"/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/ee/lib/gitlab/elastic/indexer.rb:64:in `run_indexer!'\"",
    "7787": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Faraday::TimeoutError)"
  }
}
]
```

I am currently using `jq` to extract the `failed_projects` entries, but with

`[] | select(.failed_projects != null) | . as $object | {"failed_projects"}[]`

I am getting the results in different groups:

```
{
"1082": "...",
...
}
{
"5570": "...",
...
}
{
"6760": "...",
...
}
```

**What I am trying to accomplish is to group IDs with the same exception. Something such as:**

```
[{
"Exception": "ReadTimeout",
 [{
   "ID": 2492,
   "ID": 3060
 }]
},
{
"Exception": "Deadline Exceeded",
 [{
   "ID": 1082
 }]
}]
```

Comment: `.[].failed_projects | select(. != null)` is simpler version of what you have now. It's not clear what you want as the final output. Do you want to merge all the objects into one object?

Comment: @chepner I updated the question with the desired output, grouping coincidences by value. Anything that splits the value coincidences with the IDs is OK.

Comment: The illustrative output is invalid as JSON, and contains objects with duplicate keys.   Would it be acceptable to produce valid JSON as output, without such objects?  If so, could you please provide an example of the desired JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illustrative output is invalid as JSON and has objects with repeated keys, which is probably not what you actually want, but the following jq program will produce output that is in accordance with the general problem description.  Since you do not seem to have specified the precise grouping criterion, I have taken the error message text after the last ":" as the grouping criterion.  (If, for example, you wanted to consider the text after the first ":", use "^[^:]*: *" as the regex.)

The first step gathers the `.failed_projects` together and applies `to_entries` so that we can readily access the ID and error message text:

```
[.[] | .failed_projects | to_entries[]]
```

Next we extract the grouping criterion, and use it to form the groups:

```
| map(.value |= sub("^.*: *";""))
| group_by(.value)
```

Finally, we transform the groups into JSON objects of the form:
{GROUP: ARRAY_OF_IDs}:

```
| map( .[0].value as $key
       | [.[] | .key] as $value
       | {($key): $value} )
```

Putting the above fragments together in a file, program.jq, and using the invocation:

```
jq -f program.jq input.json
```

yields the output shown below.  You will evidently want to modify the grouping criterion.  You might also wish to convert the ID strings to JSON numbers, which can be done by `tonumber` or more cautiously
 by `(tonumber? // .)`.

To understand program.jq, you might like to start with the first fragment, and then add each of the others in turn.

### Output

```
[
  {
    "Deadline Exceeded, trace": [
      "1082"
    ]
  },
  {
    "TimeoutError)": [
      "6728",
      "6747",
      "6939",
      "5570",
      "6103",
      "6188",
      "6695",
      "6721",
      "2492",
      "6760",
      "3060",
      "6941",
      "6942",
      "6947",
      "7787"
    ]
  },
  {
    "in `__raise_transport_error'": [
      "1273",
      "7201"
    ]
  },
  {
    "in `run_indexer!'\"": [
      "7707"
    ]
  }
]
```